# XPath выбор вложенного элемента с указанным предком

Tags: xpath

есть структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---- текст

```html
<aa>
    <bb>
        <dd>
            <zz>ИСКОМЫЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ(1)</zz>
         </dd>
     </bb>
</aa>

<aa>
    <cc>
       <ee>
          <ff>
              <zz>ИСКОМЫЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ(2)</zz>
          </ff>
       </ee>
    </cc>
</aa>

<kk>
    <dd>
          <zz>ИГНОРИРИМ</zz>
     </dd>
</kk>
```

---

как через XPath получить элемент zz ("искомый элемент") из такой структуры, ожидаемый ответ - 2 элемента ? ( содержимое элемента для поиска использовать нельзя, вложенность zz произвольная для каждого вхождения)

Отличие "игнорим" от "искомого" : у "искомых" предок `<aa>` и разная степень вложенности, у "игнорим" - нет предка `<aa>`

На css элементарно такое решается: `.aa .zz` , а как подобное реализовать на XPath?

Comment: элемент, который "Игноририм", имеет некое описание-свойство, которое бы отличало его от "искомого элемента"?

Comment: отличие "игнорим" от "искомого" : у "искомых" предок <aa> и разная степень вложенности, у "игнорим" - нет предка <aa>

Comment: хз, на css элементарно такое решается:
.aa .zz   , а как подобное реализовать на XPath?

Comment: ну вообще //aa //zz, только не знаю как вам скинуть пример не могу найти подобие jsfindle ну тестировать можете https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: Спасибо Равшан - все понял, разобрался))))

Answer (score 1):

Я быть может что то не так понял, но `//aa//zz`